# Migrating UI-Bootstrap modal to component based

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm studying UI-Router and UI-Bootstrap modal and had problem. the [cloned one](http://embed.plnkr.co/YQpqnY/) from UI-Bootstrap tutorial works fine, but when migrating to the [component based version](http://embed.plnkr.co/h0meyI6HafEKKFSc2Ykm/) I got the problem: it does not show the modal window. May any one help to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor function declarations as following:

From `var modalDemoCtrl = function($scope, $uibModal, $log, $document)`
to `function modalDemoCtrl($scope, $uibModal, $log, $document)`

and from `var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($uibModalInstance)`
to `function ModalInstanceCtrl()`

This way you can reference to the functions from previous code in file.

Also, you shouldn't pass `$uibModalInstance` to `ModalInstanceCtrl`.

Comment: Thank you very much @lzagkaretos after the modifications it worked (I am still trying to understand why). Sorry I'm a new-be reputation under 15, cannot vote you up.

Comment: @Oops, you can accept my answer and with the first chance, come back and vote up! Thanks.